# Issue with full screen apk

Tags: android, fullscreen, titlebar

I've just wrote my first android application, but I got a so sneaky problem :D.
The application is so simple, it has just one text box, one button and one web view.
The web view is invisible, when the button is clicked it will be visible and go to the url written in the text box
the application is full screen. 
The problem is that when I click the button it does nothing at first, the second time it works.
So as I know there is a focus problem, I think, i just themed it with

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

so there is no title bar at top. I remember that when I had title bar these acts took place

1 - I click on button
2 - the title bar appears
3 - I click on button
4 - it took affect

I can say that when I make title bar invisible, steps are the same as top.

So i need help to solve this problem, any ideas?

activity_fullscreen.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->


<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#ff3191ff">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/iptxt"
    android:layout_width="272dp" android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/iptxt" android:nextFocusLeft="@id/iptxt"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ff26b9ff"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:text="192.168.1.104"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:inputType="text" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:id="@+id/ConnectBTN"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#ff3191ff"
    android:text="Connect"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Mainwbv"
        android:visibility="invisible"></WebView>
</FrameLayout>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ir.proapp.share" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

fullscreenactivity.java

```
package ir.proapp.share;
import ir.proapp.share.util.SystemUiHider;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestUserAgent;
/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
 * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
 */
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
/**
 * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
 * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
 */
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;
/**
 * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
 * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
 */
private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;
/**
 * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
 */
private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
/**
 * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
 */
private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);


    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView.animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                        // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                        // controls.
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });
    Button connectbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ConnectBTN);
    connectbtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText iptetx=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.iptxt);
            WebView maniWV=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.Mainwbv);
            WebSettings mainSettings=maniWV.getSettings();
            mainSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mainSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.31
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31");
            maniWV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            maniWV.setWebViewClient(new Ac1());
            maniWV.loadUrl("http://"+iptetx.getText()+":9999");
        }
    });
    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
  /*  findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);  */
}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}
/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
    }
};
/**
 * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
 * previously scheduled calls.
 */
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to post your code. However, hide a title does not means that title it's no more: probably you are doing something on the title but you dont' have any feedback because it's hidden. So you need to remove the logic on the hiddentitlebar maybe.

Comment: This happens because the touch event is first intercepted by the method that triggers the title bar to appear. So if you want to trigger the website and the title bar to appear with just one click you have to pass the event through (return false in method that triggers the title bar to appear). If you use a debugger you will notice that your click event isn't triggered the first time. Are you using the pregenerated code when you choose to create a full-screen app from the wizzard?

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply , i just added code at post, i used fullscreen template in android studio. guys its just make me crazy :|

Comment: guys i just change this=>private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true; to this=> private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = false; and now it worked